# MySQL query with multiple wheres returning null

Tags: mysql

My query bellow is returning null for both setup and budget.

However if I remove everything after the value 11, it works.

Does anyone know whats going on ?

```
SELECT  SUM(setup_fee) AS setup, 
        SUM(budget) AS budget 
FROM gdn 
WHERE client = 11 
AND start_date BETWEEN 2017-03-26 AND 2017-04-30 
AND end_date BETWEEN 2017-03-26 AND 2017-04-30
```

Comment: Try enclosing each condition with a `()`

Comment: You miss the `group by` clause

Comment: What happens if you remove `client = 11 AND`?

Comment: @David Why you think so? Aggregation functions need Group by

Comment: @Jens he's filtering for a single client and there's no other not-aggregated column in his `select`, why should he need a `group by`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is neither the absence of group by nor the parentheses around the conditions, but that you have to quote those date values:

```
SELECT  SUM(setup_fee) AS setup, 
        SUM(budget) AS budget 
FROM    gdn 
WHERE   client = 11 
        AND start_date BETWEEN '2017-03-26' AND '2017-04-30'
        AND end_date BETWEEN '2017-03-26' AND '2017-04-30'
```

You can see a simplified version of the problem replicated [here](http://rextester.com/PWDWZ35829)

Comment: Thank You! I will mark as correct when it allows me

Answer (score 0):

Try using below query

```
    SELECT SUM(setup_fee) AS setup, SUM(budget) AS budget FROM gdn WHERE client = 
    11 AND ( start_date BETWEEN 2017-03-26 AND 2017-04-30) AND ( end_date BETWEEN 
    2017-03-26 AND 2017-04-30) group by client
```

Comment: can you please verify the column name for client? is client your integer column?